# why I get "AttributeError: class <class name> has no attribute <attribute name>" even I've clearly defined the attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I just started programming an assembler for a project, however, I am getting the following error while I am trying to run it. It says that some attribute is not defined even though I have defined it. I don't understand what is happening.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Assembler.py", line 27, in <module>
    main()
  File "./Assembler.py", line 22, in main
    P = Parser.inst
AttributeError: class Parser has no attribute 'inst'
```

This is the code.

```py
class Parser:
    def __init__(self, inst, type):
        self.inst = inst.strip()
        self.type = None
        self.checkType()

    def checkType(self):
        if self.inst.startswith('//') or self.inst in ['\n', '\r\n']:
            return

        elif self.inst.startswith('@'):
            self.type = 'A'

        else:
            self.type = 'C'

def main():
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as asm:
        for inst in asm:
                P = Parser.inst
                print(p.type)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: But you have defined `inst` as an instance attribute. It is not a class attribute.

Comment: there is another error and that is that for one You use `P` but then print `p.type` which will also cause an error because of case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the main function `P = Parser.inst` should be `P = Parser(inst, None)

Answer (score 1):

`Parser` is a class and didn't have `inst` value.
You must create an instance from `Parser` and pass `inst` to it. Also, you have to pass `type` parameters to your class constructor.

```
P = Parser(inst, type)
```

Answer (score 1):

You meant to create an instance of `Parser()`:

```py
def main():
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as asm:
        for inst in asm:
            p = Parser(inst, None)
            print(p.type)
```